# How did Docker know to emulate arm architecture?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, debian, cross-compiling, raspbian

This was a huge surprise for me:

Today, using Docker For Mac (18.03.1-ce-mac65), I ran a Debian Stretch image. Inside the image I mounted the latest Raspbian Stretch image (2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch-lite) using `mount`. I then used `chroot` to this mounted Raspbian filesystem.

This is where it got weird. I was able to use `apt` (without any special modifications) to install software into this mounted filesystem.

Running:

`dpkg --print-architecture`

returned: `armfh`
and the software I installed (`vim`) worked like a charm

I was even able to compile a simple program using `gcc` and run it.

But, I need to know! How is this possible?

Comment: It is starting to look like Docker For Mac runs QEMU somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/):

> Docker for Mac provides binfmt_misc multi architecture support, so you can run containers for different Linux architectures, such as arm, mips, ppc64le, and even s390x.

**EDIT**

On Linux, you can install `qemu-user-static` and then follow [this](https://github.com/computermouth/qemu-static-conf) git repo to get cross-architecture support!